# ¿Formulario que lleve a más de un link?

Tags: javascript

Buenas! En mi web tengo un formulario de contacto que una vez concretada la acción te lleva al index. Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿Es posible hacer que dependiendo el valor númerico ingresado en un campo del formulario te lleve a una u otra página?

Si la variable del campo del formulario #numerodepasajes es de valor 1 que tras enviar el form me lleve al link1 Si la variable del campo del formulario #numerodepasajes es de valor 2 que tras enviar el form me lleve al link2

Necesitaría hacer lo mismo del numero 1 al 20.

Comment: Me estoy imaginando que lo que quieres es que una vez procesado el formulario en el servidor, te redireccione a un sitio o a otro. Para eso vas a necesitar especificar qué lenguaje estás usando en el servidor, y debería ser un simple `switch...case` con una redirección.

Answer (score 1):

Este código te serviría.

La parte de cambiar de página no funciona en el snipplet porque stackoverflow lo filtra.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#frm').on('submit', function() {
     var opcion = $('input[name=opcion]:checked', '#frm').val();
     
     switch(opcion) {
       case '1':
         alert('1');
         document.location.href='pag1.html';
         break;
       case '2':
         alert('2');
         document.location.href='pag2.html';
         break;
     };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='frm'>
<input type='radio' name='opcion' value='1'/> 1<br/>
<input type='radio' name='opcion' value='2'/> 2<br/>
<input type='submit' value='   Enviar   '/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: También se podría cambiar el switch por if y así se adapta mejor

Comment: Si te fijas dice que hay números del 1 al 20. 20 if anidados no quedaría muy "elegante" que digamos.